# How to include source of symlink when downloading with rsync?

Tags: rsync, download

I would like to download clinvar from the NCBI server:

```bsh
> rsync -rvzhl --partial --append --progress --filter="merge rsync_include_pub" rsync://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/ pub/
```

`rsync_include_pub`:

```
+ /clinvar/
+ /clinvar/vcf_GRCh37/
+ /clinvar/vcf_GRCh37/clinvar.vcf.gz
+ /clinvar/vcf_GRCh37/clinvar.vcf.gz.tbi
+ /clinvar/vcf_GRCh38/
+ /clinvar/vcf_GRCh38/clinvar.vcf.gz
+ /clinvar/vcf_GRCh38/clinvar.vcf.gz.tbi
- /**
```

**How can I automatically include the source of the `*/clinvar.vcf.gz[.tbi]` links?**

I want to make sure that each run of the `rsync` command re-links the files to the up-to-date version and also ensures that the source files of the links are downloaded.

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: well, I could not find anything to this topic.
Of course, there is copy-links but I do not want to replace links with files. I only want to include referenced files in my command.